# Как можно записывать очень длинные колбэк запросы с БД

Tags: python, sql, aiogram

столкнулся с проблемой связанной с колбэк запросами.
В коде бота есть функция, которая из БД берёт название вкуса, но это название может быть большим (пример: Freeman - Лимонад с личи, ананасом и манго). Бот выдаёт ошибку при нажатии на созданную кнопку из БД. Как я понял ошибка связанная с колбэком, в него нельзя помещать больше 64 байтов, помогите решить проблему

Ошибка:

```
aiogram.utils.exceptions.ButtonDataInvalid: Button_data_invalid
```

Comment: Это так не работает. Проблема не в коллбеке, а в кол-ве разрешенных символов на кнопке. В данном случае это от 1 до 64 символов на одну кнопку. Как это можно реализовать по-другому? Вы оставляете только название Продукта, а после клика по кнопке с продуктом, появляется описание продукта + две кнопки, подтвердить или вернуться назад. Как то так

Comment: Вам требуется изменить подход к строению вашей БД. Например таблица с name_product и id_product. Вторая таблица id_product - description_product. Как пример.